# How to use the Android Studio emulator on an AMD processor computer?

Tags: flutter, windows, android-studio, android-emulator, amd-processor

My notebook has an AMD Ryzen 5 3500U processor and I'm trying to use the emulator in Android Studio and I can't get it to work properly. Most of the time the emulator only works the first time it runs when it is created. Some of the recurring problems is that even when running, it does not appear in the flutter device selection. After some research I found out that the solution may be to activate two Windows features: virtual machine platform and windows hypervisor platform. However I am not able to activate because after clicking on the checkbox and giving ok. This message returns to me:

> an error has occurred. Not all features have been successfully activated

Does anyone know how I can resolve to have these features activated?

[image]

Comment: There is another emulator that can help you: https://www.genymotion.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using an AMD PC as well and had the same issue. There were drivers that had to be configured and didn't work as expected. The workaround I did was to use genymotion as an emulator. The setup didn't require major setting changes. Here is the link to it :

https://www.genymotion.com/